# Coinbase Commerce api return a 400 error because "pricing_type" is required

Tags: javascript, coinbase-api

```
const query = {
               name: 'The Sovereign Individual',
               description: 'Mastering the Transition to the Information Age',
               local_price: {
                   amount: '100.00',
                   currency: 'USD',
                },
               pricing_type: 'fixed_price',
               metadata: {
                   customer_id: 'id_1005',
                   customer_name: 'Satoshi Nakamoto',
               },
               redirect_url: 'https://charge/completed/page',
               cancel_url: 'https://charge/canceled/page',
           };
           const opts = {
               method: 'POST',
               headers: {
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                   'X-CC-Api-Key': 'api_key',
                   'X-CC-Version': '2018-03-22',
               },
               body: JSON.stringify({
                   query
               }),
           };

            fetch('https://api.commerce.coinbase.com/charges', opts)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(jsonRes => console.log(jsonRes));
```

and the response is this

```
error:{
   message: "Required parameter missing: pricing_type"
   type: "invalid_request"
}
```

but i passed the **pricing_type** parameter as you can see,but i keep getting a 400 error with the response **invalid request**

who has an idea how i can solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body:enter code here JSON.stringify({query})
```

I believe it should be

```
body: JSON.stringify(query)
```

Edit: It's the wrong formatted JSON

Double quotes are standard practice but some services use incorrect formats. pricing_type: 'fixed_price'=>"pricing_type": 'fixed_price'

Comment: i am still getting the same 400 request error

Comment: Have you tried using double quotes around json properties? Double quotes are standard practice but some services use incorrect formats. pricing_type: 'fixed_price'=>"pricing_type": 'fixed_price',

Comment: you are a life saver, i cannot believe that actually worked , thank you very much

Comment: please update your answer properly , so others can actually understand what the problem is